# Failed to invoke the service-An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to "localhost:13001/AdminService/AdminService.svc"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, web-services, wcf

i created a wcf web service. my service uses EF5 data access to fetch data.
i have only one function named GetAllAdminList()

```
 public interface IAdminSvc
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<TblAdmin> GetAllAdminList();
}
 public class AdminSvc : IAdminSvc, IDisposable
{

    public List<TblAdmin> GetAllAdminList()
    {
        AdminBAL BalObj = new AdminBAL();
        return BalObj.GetAllAdminList();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        System.GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

Here the code part is returning the listofAdminUser from database.

Now When i am invoking the service on setting service as startup project and AdminService.svc.cs as startup page it throws me a error
**An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to "localhost:13001/AdminService/AdminService.svc" This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.**

i can assure u that my data access code works,bcoz i debug that project and i saw that it return the List perfectly! the problem occurs AFTER the return value of List

My TblAdmin Entity is like this

```
 public class TblAdmin
{
    public TblAdmin();

    public int AdminId { get; set; }
    public string AdminName { get; set; }
    public string AdminPassword { get; set; }
    public string AdminUserName { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TblCity> TblCities { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TblCompany> TblCompanies { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TblCountry> TblCountries { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TblJob> TblJobs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TblJobType> TblJobTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TblSkillGroup> TblSkillGroups { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TblSkill> TblSkills { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TblState> TblStates { get; set; }
}
```

Don't know what is the main problem,please help me to resolve it.

i have written my webcofig file like this

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ParasharPortalEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/CommonEntity.ParasharPortal.csdl|res://*/CommonEntity.ParasharPortal.ssdl|res://*/CommonEntity.ParasharPortal.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=AMIT-PC;initial catalog=ParasharPortal-1.0;user id=sa;password=samsung;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

```
<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
```

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
```

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<!--
    To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
    Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
  -->
<directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
```

Comment: Does the method BalObj.GetAllAdminList() return objects of a sub-class of TblAdmin?  I ask because a bunch of the properties are marked as virtual...

Comment: **See server logs for more details.** Did you?

Comment: @joelsand,No sub class object returning here
I think the problem in TblAdimin Class because when i returning a custom class of non virtual properties and associate all it's properties in query it's working fine
What is main problem still not clear to me?